# Access denied error installing MySql Python connector 64-bit on Windows 10 via .msi

Tags: python, mysql, installation, windows-10

I have successfully installed most of MySql on Windows 10, and have a working database. The only part that will not install is the 64-bit Python connector.

[image]

I am successfully using the connector via pip --install, but it is unclear if I have a 64-bit or 32-bit version (as I am having issues with the int64 python type).

First question ... do I need to run this msi at all (mysql-connector-python-8.0.23-windows-x86-64bit.msi)?

Second question ... even if I try to run as an Administrator, it still fails. If I look at the folder in question (c:\program files\Windows Apps), Administrators only have View rights. A "Trusted Installer" has full rights it seems. Is there a special trick to this?

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but my SO search hasn't returned anything that covers this precise issue.

Comment: I'm unclear how you got Python installed there to begin with.  How did you install Python itself?  And yes, that Python installation is 64 bit.  There is no "int64" type in Python, so I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: @TimRoberts I downloaded from Python.org originally: I have no idea where that complicated path comes from. To be more precise it is the numpy.int64 type.

Comment: are you installing from local drive?

Comment: @NonoLondon I was using the web-based install this time. When I first installed MySQL I downloaded the package locally and installed from there. At the time the install refused to perform the python connector install. However, you have given me some pointers on numpy.int64 on another thread, so i will give those a go instead.

Comment: you can't install the python connector and it is still unclear wehat the installer needs, in my system 3.92, it tells me tht  i am to new. So i ignired it there is no need for it. in VS code python is recognized and with pip install you get all python needs

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with this, but I was able to fix it!

It turns out the problem is the Python version from windows Store, that has a restricted folder with no access to modify it, due to windows restrictions to prevent piracy.
The WindowsApps folder is one of the few that doesn't allow modification from users.
To solve this  problem, I would recommend to just simply install Python from their offical website, and in that way you won't have this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same issue. Instead of installing the latest version in MySql installer, I installed the very old version of the connector firstly. Then upgraded it to the latest again using mysql installer and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your permissions of the folder**

Step 1 -: Locate the installation directory that is giving you problems. Right-click it and choose **Properties**. Keep in mind that sometimes you might have to change the security permissions for the parent folder as well in order to fix this problem.

Step 2-: Go to the **Security** tab and click **Edit**.

Step 3-: In Group or user names section select **SYSTEM** or **Everyone** and click the **Full control** in the **Allow** column. If you don’t have SYSTEM or Everyone available, you’ll need to add it. To do that, click the **Add** button.

Step 4-: Select Users or Groups window will now appear. In the Enter the object names to select field enter **Everyone** or **SYSTEM** and click **Check Names** button. If your input is valid, click the OK button.

Step 5-: **SYSTEM** or **Everyone** group will now be added. Select it and check **Full control** in the **Allow** column.

Step 6-:     Click **Apply** and **OK** to save changes.

Comment: The thing is that the root folder c:\program files\WindowsApps has only given Full Control to TrustedInstaller and System. Administrator only has View access, and hence cannot edit the security permissions. Hence in Step 2, there is no Edit button. I am surprised that there are parts of the file system to which Administrators do not have access. As MS says: "Administrators have complete control over the PC. They can change any settings and access all of the files and programs stored on the PC".

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution on this problem.
This might happen due to permissions of Windows APPs so I just **uninstalled** my Python 3.9 (**Windows Apps Version**) and kept official version of python or if you don't have you can simply install it from python official site.
This will surely work for you!